# java: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm using CXF 2.1 to generate java code from a wsdl, but I'm getting the following error:

```
WSDLToJava Error: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.checkSupported(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:173)
```

How do I fix this error, can I use a previous version of CXF or anything else to fix it?

Answer (score 83):

RPC/encoded is a vestige from before SOAP objects were defined with XML Schema. It's [not widely supported](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2008/12/rpcencoded-web-services-on-java-16.html) anymore. You will need to generate the stubs using [Apache Axis 1.0](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/axis/1_4/), which is from the same era.

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://someurl?WSDL
```

You will need the following jars or equivalents in the -cp classpath param:

- [axis-1.4.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/axis/axis-1.4.jar.zip)
- [commons-logging-1.1.ja](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonslogging111jar.htm)
- [commons-discovery-0.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/commons-discovery/commons-)
- [jaxrpc-1.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jaxrpc/jaxrpc-api-1.1.jar.zip)
- [saaj-1.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/axis2-saaj/axis2-saaj-1.1.jar.zip)
- wsdl4j-1.4.jar
- [activation-1.1.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar)
- [mail-1.4.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java-mail/java-mail-1.4.jar.zip)

This will generate similar stubs to wsimport.

*Alternatively*, if you are not using the parts of the schema that require rpc/encoded, you can download a copy of the WSDL and comment out those bits. Then run wsimport against the local file.

If you look at the WSDL, the following bits are using rpc/encoded:

```
<soap:body use="encoded"
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
```

Comment: Is there any documentation available for this problem in internet?

Comment: On the last Axis 1.4 distribution I have different jars naming and mail-1.4.jar is not present. It does not work as is. (I followed your Axis 1.0 link)

Comment: u ll need to add it explicitly.mail-1.x.jar and activation-1.x.jar

Comment: I tried your method and I get "java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times", which is probably due to the fact that I'm trying to import from a web service that requires authentication, how can I deal with authentication using your method?

Comment: I had removed use=encoded attribute, from <soap:body> and wsimport stopped complaining anymore and generated artifacts out of the wsdl. Is this a right approach ? Or it will have any impact.

Comment: @Albert, for maven see my post below

Answer (score 20):

I used Axis 1.4 as Chase Seibert suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415326/1407228), although the download link given in that answer doesn't work. The alternative download link I used gave me different libraries. Below are the steps I followed to generate my code.

Go to http://apache.is.co.za/axis/axis/java/1.4/ and download **axis-bin-1_4.zip**.

Extract it, and you should have the following files (among others):

- axis.jar
- commons-discovery-0.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- jaxrpc.jar
- saaj.jar
- wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

Execute WSDL2Java using the following command (replacing the URL, of course):

```
java -cp axis.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;jaxrpc.jar;saaj.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://someURL?WSDL
```

This will generate your Java files.

**P.S.:** This seems to work equally well using Axis 1.2.1.

Comment: Two classes are reported missing resulting in Attachment support being disabled. To fix this, get mail.jar and activation.jar and add them to the command.

Comment: Add mailapi.jar and activation.jar as @Marco Brochet stated. I used -classpath and replaced ";" with ":". java -classpath axis.jar:commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:commons-discovery-0.2.jar:jaxrpc.jar:saaj.jar:wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar:mailapi.jar:activation.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java  https://api.clickatell.com/soap/webservice.php?WSDL

Answer (score 7):

May be this would help with CXF. Alteast it worked for me.
I edited the WSDL file and removed all references of SOAP-ENC and created type `ArrayOfString` in below way

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="String" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 7):

In case someone would like to use maven: (plus [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ws_ovw_soap_syntax_lit.html) some info about WSDL binding styles)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Use your .wsdl location here-->
                        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- Here the libraries that you need to call the Axis WS client -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- activation+mail: To stop Axis generating WARNING about "Attachment support being disabled" -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is whats happened to me (old wsdl in the same folder): https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20180831-CodeGenerationWithMavenCxfPlugin.html

"Obviously, something else was causing the problem for the Maven plugin. After a lot of trial and error, I finally got to the bottom of it. There was another WSDL file in the same folder and that one was for an RPC/literal web service. The plugin failed because it was trying to process it although the full path to my WSDL path in the configuration didn't point to it in any way."

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help to someone. I checked the above and it did not work for me.

I downloaded Apache [Axis 1.2.1](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis/1_2_1/) then changed the command as like that

```
java -classpath full_path/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:full_path/commons-discovery-0.2.jar:full_path/jaxrpc.jar:full_path/saaj.jar:full_path/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar:full_path/mailapi.jar:full_path/activation.jar:full_path/mail.jar -Xmx128M org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -pcom.package -T1.1 -ofull_path_of_output file:full_path_of_wsdl
```

Answer (score -4):

just extract,and Execute WSDL2Java? using the following command (replacing the URL, of course):

```
java -cp axis.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;jaxrpc.jar;saaj.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://someURL?WSDL
```