# Dealing with SOAP encoding in RPC/Encoded Web Service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xmlbeans

I can't manage to create code from WSDL that is in RPC/encoded style - does anyone know which framewok can do that?

Axis2 with adb and xmlbeans maping aint working (can't deal with soap-encoding in response)
straightforeward use of XMLbeans doesn't generate request messages (as they are not types in wsdl) -so I'm not as far as that...

Any suggestions?

Comment: a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0

Comment: I think it's not exactly duplicate but the problem is teh same :-)

Comment: i'll rephrase - this is NOT a duplicate, but the same problem worded differently. hope that's much better :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPC encoding is obsolete and not used any more.
Axis 2.0 does not support it but previous versions of Axis should do the job. Check  [axi2 rpc support](http://www.bluesunrise.com:8080/webcontent/rproxy/axis_apache/axis2/java/core/docs/Axis2-rpc-support.html)

Comment: Falls it wouldn't be used, there wouldn't be such questions. It is still used 1,5 year after your post.

Comment: It only exists due to legacy code that companies have not had the time to "upgrade". No new project would ever use `RPC encoding` and it is not `WS-I BP` compliant