# WSDL conversion to Java

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I have to convert a WSDL to java classes for creating WS server and that WSDL uses RPC/encoded.
This encoding is not supported in cxf or in JWS 2.0.
So I have commmented those lines mentioning RPC/Encoded  `use="encoded"/>`

I have created the java classes, but my client's wsdl will still look for  use="encoded"/> and currently whatever wsdl my app is generation (using cxf framework), there is no encoded attribute in SOAP:body

Will this create a problem, I am new to web service and I am currently learning stage, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the WSDL you have to match uses an encoding that your library doesn't support. So you either have to change the WSDL or change libraries.

This question seems to address the same situation: [java: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0)

Comment: I knew about answer you are referring, but I was expecting some other solution other than creating a server from Axis 1.4.Currently I was trying with CXF.... It would be nice if could change the client side and unfortunately I could not, So my choice would building the endpoint in axis 1.4 Thanks for answering