# Web service response contains an invalid XML character

Tags: java, web-services, axis

My application is connecting to a web service rpc/encoded. Im using Axis 1.4.
When the webservice sends a response, it sends an invalid character then an exception:

```
http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
  An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x3) was found in the element content of the document.
```

The xml encoding is "ISO-8859-1". I think that is the problem.

My question is: Is there any configuration that i can make in my application to accept this invalid character ?

Comment: Without more details on the web service and how you're calling it and parsing the results it's hard to tell. The problem may be at the server.

Comment: The XML 1.0 spec forbids control characters such as U+0003 regardless of the character encoding, you can't even escape them using `&#03;`. If the service is complaining that _you_ sent _it_ an invalid character then you'll have to fix your client, if the client is complaining about a character it received in the response then you'll have to take it up with the service owner.

Comment: As a quick'n'dirty solution you can write a proxy that will remove illegal characters from response.

Comment: Thank's for help. I threw the problem to the web service owner. Btw @KonstantinV.Salikhov your solution worked fine.

Comment: The web service owner told that i need to change my application to acept "ISO-8859-1", they can do nothing about it. 
I still waiting some help.

Comment: @JimGarrison the parse are made by Axis after xml deserialization. I cant see the code. I need to set the encoding as "ISO-8859-1" in somewhere that i dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem putting a method inside org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler to search and destroy illegal characters before parse the the content inside xml response ahead.

[To create your own LogHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisClientConfiguration/ViewSOAPMessages)

[The method to search and destroy illegal characters](http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/02/invalid-xml-characters-when-valid-utf8_5873.html)

Inside logMessages method of your new LogHandler put the following:

`private void logMessages(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
     ...
     msgContext.setResponseMessage(new Message( 
                stripNonValidXMLCharacters(((Message) msgContext
                .getResponseMessage()).getSOAPPartAsString())));
     ...
}`

Comment: There is a way somewhere with Axis 1.4 to auto-generate the stubs to deal with "rpc/encoded". Then you wouldn't have to intercept responses. However, I read that it does not work with CXF, and you are permanently bound to Axis 1.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0 .

Answer (score 2):

"My application is connecting to a web service rpc/encoded."

That's the catch. The service is "rpc/encoded" which is non-WS-I-compliant. The developers decided after some heated discussion sometime in the past [not to 'fix' this error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2025).