# SOAP 1.2 mtom enabled service sending LF characters in response PDF

Tags: pdf, soap, mtom

We are building a SOAP 1.2 MTOM enabled web service which returns 2 PDFs , this web service is also hosted on a linux server. Our issue is - these PDFs are not being parsed due to existence of LFs. We found that while building the response , JAXWS framework is adding these LFs in response. How to convert these LFs to CRLFs so that the response can be parsed by web service consumer?

Please let me know if any solution to the relative thread "How to retain CRLF in JAX-WS SOAP webmethod response?".

Answer (score 0):

you can eliminate the LF chars in response using webservice handler.

follow the link: [Web service response contains an invalid XML character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697323/web-service-response-contains-an-invalid-xml-character)