# Consuming old axis generated WSDL

Tags: cxf, axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate the java stubs for  the following WSDL http://telviva.com/local/telvivaapi.wsdl
If I try and use CXF I get the following error:

> WSDLToJava Error: Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported with CXF

Many forums online say I need to use axis to generate them, but using axis gives me the following error:

> java.io.IOException: No 'message' attribute in  for operation 'delete_access'

Can anyone suggest how I might consume this WSDL please?

Comment: I faced similar error CXF doesn't support JAX-RPC. On lots of effort found that even axis 2 doesn't support JAX-RPC. only Axis 1 supports JAX-RPC you can find alternative solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0

Comment: I followed these instructions to the letter, that what gave me the IOException (I was using axis 1.4)