# Maven jaxb2 plugin not generating operations

Tags: java, maven, magento, wsdl, maven-jaxb2-plugin

When I generate Java classes from the WSDL file found here : http://wsdl-bug.s3.amazonaws.com/magento.xml, it successfully generates classes but no operations.

It generates the classes for the types and it generates classes for  requests/responses parameters but it does not generate any method for the operations.

Here's my maven plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>magento.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://wsdl-bug.s3.amazonaws.com/magento.xml</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, it may be an issue as the Webservice is **rpc/encoded** which is quite old and the plugin may not be able to handle that. I tried parsing the same wsdl using cxf-codegen which straight away gave the error _Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported with CXF_. I would suggest if there is no alternative to this wsdl try using Apache Axis 1.0 as detailed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jrao77.  This didn't work for me but the cxf-codegen plugin did! http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html