# Liferay 7 Plugin SOAP Service Locator

Tags: web-services, soap, liferay-7, service-locator

In Liferay 7, JournalArticleSoapService is no longer part of the portal and we need to deploy a service-wsdd.jar to access SOAP services regarding JournalArticle.

However, I can't find any documentation which described the way to load the service. In 6.2, I use JournalArticleServiceSoapServiceLocator but this not available in com.liferay.journal.service.jar nor in com.liferay.journal.api.jar

The given example Liferay's documentation (https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/soap-web-services) is about Company, User and UserGroup. But all those are part of Liferay Portal and the Locator is available without including additional jar file.

Clearly, how should I load a SOAP service that is in a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured this out using WSDL2Java which generates the needed locator services then I generated a jar file from those classes; as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412772/java-rpc-encoded-wsdls-are-not-supported-in-jaxws-2-0)